# kubernetes popeye report JSON to cvs with JQ

Tags: csv, kubernetes, jq, export-to-csv

I need to reformat the Popeye Kubernetes report in a spreadsheet.
I used jq but it's a bit tricky.

```
{
  "popeye": {
    "score": 90,
    "grade": "A",
    "sanitizers": [
      {
        "sanitizer": "cluster",
        "tally": {
          "ok": 1,
          "info": 0,
          "warning": 0,
          "error": 0,
          "score": 100
        },
        "issues": {
          "Version": [
            {
              "group": "__root__",
              "level": 0,
              "message": "[POP-406] K8s version OK"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The best format to export to csv would be something like :

```json
{
  "sanitizer" : "cluster",
  "kube-object" : "Version",
  "group": "__root__",
  "level": 0,
  "message": "[POP-406] K8s version OK"
}
```

I tried a lot of jq command without success.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for a CSV export but you are showing an object as desired format. So, I interpreted the object's fields as CSV columns:

```
["sanitizer", "kube-object", "group", "level", "message"],
(.popeye.sanitizers[] | [.sanitizer] + (
  .issues | to_entries[] | [.key, (.value[] | .group, .level, .message)])
)
| @csv
```

```
"sanitizer","kube-object","group","level","message"
"cluster","Version","__root__",0,"[POP-406] K8s version OK"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/YOVN2aBEp0)

Use `jq`'s `--raw-output` or `-r` parameter to get proper CSV formatting. Also, remove the first line if you don't need headers.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `map()` along with `+` operator in order to produce the JSON as in the format presented within the question such as

```json
jq - r '.[].sanitizers | map({sanitizer}+{"kube-object" : "Version"}+.issues.Version[])[]'
```

where

```json
{"kube-object" : "Version"}
```

has been added as a non-existing key-value pair for the source JSON

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/CjUOlAf2at)</kbd>

If your aim is to generate comma-seperated key-value pairs line by line, then consider using

```json
jq -r '.[].sanitizers | map({sanitizer}+{"kube-object" : "Version"}+.issues.Version[])[] | to_entries[] | "\(.key), \(.value)"'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/HRrQsSsRM7)</kbd>